# Setting title attribute for a disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form. Before the user can submit it, they have to agree to my privacy policy.

Before accepting the privacy policy, the button is disabled and look like this:
`<input type="submit" value="Invia" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" disabled="disabled">`.

Question is: how do I display via jquery a different title based on the disabled property? If the button is disabled, title should be "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue". If the button is not disabled, it should be "Send your request".

I tried different approaches, but none is working.

My guess would have been something like:

```
    /* title for disabled submit */
    if ($("input.wpcf7-submit").attr('disabled') == "disabled") {
      $("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" );
    }
    else {
      $("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Send your request" );
    }
```

Comment: It would be no good to runs this code only once – you need it to run when the “accepted” state of the privacy policy changes. Assuming that accepting it is done via a checkbox, you should bind an event handler for the `change` event to that. In that handler function, read the checkbox’ current status, and set the title of your button accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe thanks a lot! You gave me the right hint, I wrote:


`  /* title for disabled submit button */  
   $("input.Privacy").change(function() {
     if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
       $("input.submitInput").attr( "title", "Invia la richiesta" );
     }
     else {
       $("input.submitInput").attr( "title", "Per continuare devi sottoscrivere l'informativa sulla Privacy" );
     }
  });`
and it works perfectly!

Comment: even better
` /* title for disabled submit button */
$("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" );
$("input.Privacy").change(function() { if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) { $("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Send your request" ); } else { $("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" ); } });`
because the default prop for the checkbox is unchecked, so I display the proper title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based on the hint that CBroe gave me in a comment to this question. I write it here for everybody's convenience.

```
/* title for disabled submit button */
$("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" );
$("input.Privacy").change(function() { 
 if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
  $("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Send your request" ); 
 } 
 else { 
  $("input.wpcf7-submit").attr( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" ); 
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `prop` to set the `title` attribute:

```
if ($("input.wpcf7-submit").attr('disabled') == "disabled") {
  $("input.wpcf7-submit").prop( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" );
}
else {
  $("input.wpcf7-submit").prop( "title", "Send your request" );
}
```

don 't forget to wrap it in `$document.ready(function () { ... })`.

Comment: @EternalHour and @Jorge, I'm afraid it doesn't work. I tried this approach and also the `$("input[disabled].wpcf7-submit")`, and `$("input[disabled ='disabled'].wpcf7-submit")` and `$('.wpcf7-submit').is(':disabled')` and so many others... result is always "Send your request" to be shown. you can see it (in italian) at [link](http://www.il-polistirolo.it/vendita-polistirolo-polistirene/decorazione-architettonica/profili-in-polistirolo-polistirene-espanso-eps/). Both with `prop()` and `attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it goes like this...

```
$(functions() {
    if( $('.wpcf7-submit').is(':disabled') ){
        $('.wpcf7-submit').attr( "title", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue" );
    }
});
```

You don't need an `else` because otherwise the default title will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need. You can run the snippet to check.

```js
    $("#accCheck").change(function () {
        // this represents the checkbox that was checked
        // do something with it
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("#btnAcc").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#btnAcc").prop("value", "Send your request");
        } else {
            $("#btnAcc").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#btnAcc").prop("value", "Please agree to our privacy policy to continue");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="accCheck" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">I accept the conditions
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="btnAcc" value="Invia" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: I wrote: I wrote:


`  /* title for disabled submit button */  
   $("input.Privacy").change(function() {
     if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
       $("input.submitInput").attr( "title", "Invia la richiesta" );
     }
     else {
       $("input.submitInput").attr( "title", "Per continuare devi sottoscrivere l'informativa sulla Privacy" );
     }
  });`
and it works perfectly!

TY

Comment: If it works you can click the V the accept my answer.

Comment: actually, your solution does not change the title; it operates on the button content; the hint that CBros gave me in the comment to my question, instead, made me solve my problem changing the title attribute